# Angularjs Controller not showing in the view

Tags: angularjs, controller

I have been taking an online lesson for Angular and I cannot figure out why my message will not show in the view. I have removed the controller from global namespace. Can someone please help?

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app="app">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.1" data-semver="1.6.1" 
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"> 
 </script>
 <script src="Script1.js"></script>


<title></title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainController">
<h1>Hello {{ message }}</h1>
</body>
</html>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
$scope.message = "Hello Again";

});`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ng-app name is wrong , change it as

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
$scope.message = "Hello Again";
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainController">
<h1>Hello {{ message }}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the same app name which you used in your js file. please changed your ng-app name to 'myApp'

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

<html ng-app="app"> // change this app to myApp.
```